# How to get a recent date value in date format from json with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 questions based on the example below.

1- How can I get the closest 'jsonData.te' value to today?

2- How can I do the for loop in reverse without breaking this structure? (for example, it will look at key: 27 first, it will end when it finds the value of te there)

Thanks..

```js
var demo = document.getElementsByName("test");
var today = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    for (const dem of demo) {
    const jsonObject = dem.getAttribute("value");
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonObject);
    console.log(jsonData.te);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 21, "sd": "2021-05-22", "te": "de1"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 22, "sd": "2021-05-21", "te": "de2"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 23, "sd": "2021-05-20", "te": "de3"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 24, "sd": "2021-05-23", "te": "de4"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 25, "sd": "2021-05-25", "te": "de5"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 26, "sd": "2021-05-24", "te": "de6"}'>
<input type="hidden" name="test" value='{"key": 27, "sd": "2021-05-26", "te": "de7"}'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can get the result you want.

```
function sortt(son) {
    input = document.getElementsByName("test");
    var today = new Date();
    var today_t = today.getTime();
    var arre = [];
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        value = input[i].value;
        ndate = JSON.parse(value).sd;
        te = JSON.parse(value).te;
        var d1 = new Date(ndate);
        var s1 = d1.getTime();
        difff = s1 - today_t;
        if (difff > 0) {
            arre.push({ difff: difff, tei: te });
        }
    }
    arre.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.difff - b.difff;
    });
    return arre[0].tei;
}

var relist = sortt(0);
console.log(relist);
```